# powershell array returning unexpected results

Tags: powershell

I have an array of objects that is not returning data as expected when I try to filter it.

Data:

```
Date           Batch
----           -----
04/08/2008     1
04/08/2008     2
04/08/2008     3
04/08/2008     10
04/08/2008     11
```

My code:

```
$table = @{}
$table = import-csv e:\report.csv
Foreach($item in $table.GetEnumerator())
{
    If (($item.date -eq '4/8/2008') -and ($item.batch -le 100) )
    {
        $item
    }
}
```

I would expect it to return all items but I only get:

```
Date           Batch
----           -----
04/08/2008     1
04/08/2008     10
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you read from a CSV, all values are strings. If you want to do a numerical comparison, you need numeric types. You can simply cast --> `[int]$item.batch -le 100`. The alternative is let the left-hand side be the data type you want --> `100 -ge $item.batch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?

The fact that **strings are *not* numbers** :-)

`Import-Csv` treats all column values as *strings*, so you're comparing the string `"3"` to `100`, not the *number* `3` - and alphabetically, `100` precedes `3` (first character `"1"` vs first character `"3"`).

Cast `$item.batch` to a numerical type:

```
foreach($item in Import-Csv E:\report.csv)
{
    If (($item.date -eq '4/8/2008') -and ([int]$item.batch -le 100) )
    {                                      # Look, here
        $item
    }
}
```

... or, flip the operands around, so that the numerical reference value (`100`) is the left-hand side argument:

```
If (($item.date -eq '4/8/2008') -and (100 -gt $item.batch) )
```

This will cause PowerShell to convert `$item.batch` to a numerical type before comparing

Comment: I knew it was a simple thing I was overlooking! Thank you!